# Como fazer um input password (campo de senha) no PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt-4

Pra usar um campo parecido com `input` do HTML em Pyqt4, eu costumo utilizar o `QtGui.QLineEdit`.

Mas como faço para poder fazer um campo parecido com o `input` password, que é um campo específico para digitar senhas?

Tem como definir os "asteriscos" que ocultam o texto digitado no próprio QLineEdit, ou tem algum específico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setEchoMode`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setEchoMode) passando como parâmetro o enum `QLineEdit.Password` ou `QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit`

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

#...

txtPw = QtGui.QLineEdit()
txtPw.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
txtPw.show()
```

- **`QLineEdit.Password`** Mostra apenas "asteriscos" ao digitar algum texto
- **`QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit`** Mostra o caracter digitado e, logo em seguida, troca por um "asterisco"

[Veja outros valores do enum `echoMode` aqui](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum)

[Baseado nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634843/password-form-in-pyqt)

Comment: Valeu, jovem. Era isso mesmo :p